# How can I create an instance of KClass<MutableList<Foo<*>>>?

Tags: kotlin

I need to pass the type of a class as a parameter because of type erasure.

```
class Abc<T : Any>(private val clazz: KClass<T>)
```

I can get it to work when T is something like `String`, but I'm having trouble creating the argument for `clazz` when the type is `KClass<MutableList<Foo<*>>>`.

I've tried doing `mutableListOf<Foo<*>>()`, but then I get `KClass<MutableList<out Foo<*>>>` instead of `KClass<MutableList<Foo<*>>>`.

How can I create the `KClass` instance that I need?

Comment: A KClass won't carry information about the type, so you can only use `MutableList::class`  without a type. Generics will only allow you to create an `Abc<MutableList<*>>` if `T` is used for a `KClass` parameter type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to construct an `Abc<MutableList<Foo<*>>>` so its methods end up taking and returning `MutableList<Foo<*>>`, it's enough to cast it:

```
val abc = Abc(MutableList::class) as Abc<MutableList<Foo<*>>>
```

(you could cast the argument to `KClass<MutableList<Foo<*>>>` instead, but this makes no difference).

But as Tenfour04's comment says, there are no different `KClass` instances for `MutableList<Foo<*>>`, `MutableList<String>`, etc. so:

1. you can't expect actually different behavior for `Abc<MutableList<Foo<*>>>` and `Abc<MutableList<AnythingElse>>` except for the casts the compiler inserts;
2. by using type erasure in this way, you are giving up some type safety, and make possible `ClassCastException`s far from the original cast.